# How to hide status bar in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-statusbar

I referred this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html). In that if the user clicks on EditText(for ex To: ) at that time  keyboard will be popped out and at the same time the user can be able to scroll to see all remaining views(ex: compose,subject, send button) in that screen. Similarly in my app I have one activity in that I am having some widgets or views.
    Suppose if the user clicks on Edittext which is in my Activity then keyboard is popping out and i can be able to scroll to see remaining views. But if i give this attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in manifest i was unable to scroll to see remaining views but if give attribute `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` like this in manifest I can be able to scroll to see remaining view but there is status bar in that screen, here I want full screen and even if the keyboard is popped out I can scroll to see remaining views..? what changes I have to made for this..?

Comment: @user448250: Note that you cannot hide the status bar in Android 3.0, and there is a decent chance that you will not be able to hide the status bar going forward. In Android 3.0, the status bar houses the BACK and HOME buttons, so the status bar needs to be always available.

Comment: I have just managed to hide both the title and status bar on the emulator with 3.0, API level 11.

Comment: Full screen should be still allowed, user usually doesn't want to see status bar when playing full screen game.

Comment: @user448250 Did you ever find this out?

Comment: What is activity at all? It it some xml file in your website folder?

Answer (score 199):

Write this in your Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Check Doc here : https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

and your app will go fullscreen. no status bar, no title bar. :)

Comment: Note that this will not work if your activity superclass calls setContentView in the onCreate method - the app will quit with an exception.

Comment: @Ron I was testing on API level 8. It's possible the behaviour is different on other levels?

Comment: Is this valid for all versions from 2.3.x to 4.x ?

Comment: In this case how to apply scroll view?.. If it applies,is it works? what we can do to work scroll view here.

Comment: This still prevents the screen from scrolling when the software keyboard is being shown.

Comment: Carefull, Call it after setContentView(). Also, better use addFlags() to save previous flags.

Comment: It crashes, even if I place it before or after the `setContentView()`

Comment: Use it before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` if it crash

Comment: Is there any workaround to hide status bar globally ? setting this in every activity sounds stupid

Comment: It kills me that SO put top answers at the bottom of the page :facepalm:

Answer (score 25):

Use this code for hiding the status bar in your app and easy to use

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 21):

Use theme `"Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` and try setting `"android:windowSoftInputMode=adjustResize"` for the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml.` You can find details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: With the above approach, my status bar can be hidden when the app is running full screen, however, I can still see the status bar while I swiping down the page. Is there is a way if I don't want the status bar at all?

Answer (score 20):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
 } else {
     View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
      int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
      decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
      ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
      actionBar.hide();
 }
```

Comment: I've noticed that when I use this method, showing the soft-keyboard moves the views above the editText, instead of resizing things. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

If you need this in one activity, you have to put in onCreate, before setContentView:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

setContentView(R.layout.your_screen);
```

Comment: This way makes keyboard covers input field in webview.

Comment: @AllenVork any solution?

Answer (score 12):

Add this to your Activity class

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // some your code
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are hiding the status bar do this in onCreate(for Activity) and onCreateView/onViewCreated(for Fragment)

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And don't forget to clear the flag when exiting the activity or else you will have the full screen in your whole app after visiting this activity.
To clear do this in your onDestroy(for Activity) or onDestroyView(for Fragment)

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Answer (score 9):

Use this for your `Activity`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are working with higher API then you may have noticed the flags as mentioned by the above answers i.e. `FLAG_FULLSCREEN` and `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN` are deprecated.

To cover up the whole screen you can define a custom theme:

```xml
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <style name="ActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Add the theme in your *activity* in the `manifest` like `android:theme="@style/ActivityTheme"` and you are done.

**Note**: You can also add pre-defined *@android* themes directly in your manifest: `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"`.
In such cases make sure your activity extends `Activity()` not `AppCompatActivity()` although it's not recommended.

Answer (score 7):

```
void hideStatusBar() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
           getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        } else {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
    }
```

You can use this method to hide the status bar. And this is important to hide the action bar too. In this case, you can **getSupportActionBar().hide()** if you have extended the activity from support lib like Appcompat or you can simply call **getActionBar().hide()** after the method mentioned above. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Change the theme of application in the `manifest.xml` file.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Strangely enough this shows an orange bar at the top of the screen. The notification bar is hidden though.

Answer (score 5):

**Use this code:**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.youractivityxmlname);
```

Answer (score 5):

This code hides status bar.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

to hide action bar write this line:-

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

both lines can be written collectively to hide Action bar and status bar. all these lines must be written before `setContentView` method call in `onCreate` method.

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In AndroidManifest.xml -> inside the activity which you want to use, add the following:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
//this is for hiding action bar
```

and in MainActivity.java -> inside onCreate() method, add the following :

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
//this is for hiding status bar
```

Answer (score 5):

You can hide by using styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="HiddenTitleTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

just call this in your manifest like this `android:theme="@style/HiddenTitleTheme"`

Answer (score 5):

this is the best solution for me , just write this line in your theme.xml

```
<style name="MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
...
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
...
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can hide status bar by setting it's color to transperant using **xml**. Add **statusBarColor** item to your activity theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: pls add some explanation code only answers are bit confusing to others

Answer (score 4):

As FLAG_FULLSCREEN is deprecated from android R. You can use below code to hide status bar.

```
 @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

           window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    } else {

           window.setFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
```

Comment: This is incorrect, they do not behave the same the inset just does like           `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Answer (score 3):

Hide StatusBar

```
private void hideSystemBars() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

show StatusBar

```
private void showSystemBars() {
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);
    WindowInsetsControllerCompat windowInsetsController = ViewCompat.getWindowInsetsController(getWindow().getDecorView());
    if (windowInsetsController == null) {
        return;
    }
    // Configure the behavior of the hidden system bars
    windowInsetsController.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    // Hide both the status bar and the navigation bar
    windowInsetsController.show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
}
```

for top camera cut with screen

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:ignore="NewApi">shortEdges</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Light_NoActionBar);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
    , WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity__splash_screen);
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: I did not have much idea of what exactly AppCompat is, been just using it. And these three lines did the job.

Comment: Pity is that Google's own documentation, as always, is incorrect how to achieve this. Maybe they should copy paste this code.

Answer (score 2):

including android api 30, this works for me

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 30) {
        window.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        actionBar?.hide()
    } else {
        window.decorView.windowInsetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The clean and scalable approach to show and hide system UI I stick to, which works for different Android Api levels:

```
object SystemBarsCompat {
    private val api: Api =
        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> Api31()
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R -> Api30()
            else -> Api()
        }

    fun hideSystemBars(window: Window, view: View, isImmersiveStickyMode: Boolean = false) =
        api.hideSystemBars(window, view, isImmersiveStickyMode)

    fun showSystemBars(window: Window, view: View) = api.showSystemBars(window, view)

    fun areSystemBarsHidden(view: View): Boolean = api.areSystemBarsHidden(view)

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private open class Api {
        open fun hideSystemBars(window: Window, view: View, isImmersiveStickyMode: Boolean = false) {
            val flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

            view.systemUiVisibility = if (isImmersiveStickyMode) {
                flags or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            } else {
                flags or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            }
        }

        open fun showSystemBars(window: Window, view: View) {
            view.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        }

        open fun areSystemBarsHidden(view: View) = view.systemUiVisibility and View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION != 0
    }

    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
    private open class Api30 : Api() {

        open val defaultSystemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_SWIPE

        override fun hideSystemBars(window: Window, view: View, isImmersiveStickyMode: Boolean) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
            view.windowInsetsController?.let {
                it.systemBarsBehavior =
                    if (isImmersiveStickyMode) WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
                    else defaultSystemBarsBehavior
                it.hide(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
            }
        }

        override fun showSystemBars(window: Window, view: View) {
            window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
            view.windowInsetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars())
        }

        override fun areSystemBarsHidden(view: View) = !view.rootWindowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private class Api31 : Api30() {
        override val defaultSystemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_DEFAULT
    }
}
```

And for example to hide system bars, it can be called from a `Fragment`:

```
SystemBarsCompat.hideSystemBars(requireActivity().window, view)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the official documentation about hiding the Status Bar on Android 4.0 and lower and on Android 4.1 and higher

Please, take a look at it:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 0):

We cannot prevent the status appearing in full screen mode in (4.4+) kitkat or above devices, so try a hack to block the status bar from expanding.

Solution is pretty big, so here's the link of SO:

[StackOverflow : Hide status bar in android 4.4+ or kitkat with Fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984476/hide-status-bar-in-android-4-4-or-kitkat-with-fullscreen)

Comment: I think you are wrong, please take a look at the official info about hiding the status bar https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Comment: Jose, I will check the information on given link and will update the answer if needed. This question/answer added an year ago when there was not an official solution for this scenario. May be in next release or versions google/android have added the API/method for the same. If they have provided the solution then its a delight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This solution work for me :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
           getWindow().setFlags(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.ACTION_NEXT_HTML_ELEMENT);
           getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3328);
    }else{
           requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
           this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_hse_video_details);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // If the Android version is lower than Jellybean, use this call to hide
    // the status bar.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
       View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
       // Hide the status bar.
       int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
       decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
       // Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
       // status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
       ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
       actionBar.hide();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used in `Manifest`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: Probably depends on theme. In my case an exception occured: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity."

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [Google Documents](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status) you can use this method for android 4.1 and above, call this method before setContentView()

```
public void hideStatusBar() {
    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOption = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    view.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOption);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add or Replace in Style.xml File

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can hide status bar in Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher by using setSystemUiVisibility()

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

As per google document we should never show the action bar if the
status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.

```
actionBar?.hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm very late to answer.
I use the following piece of code in a relative java file for this purpose

```
Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Compose** then you can import

```
implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:0.17.0"
```

then in your screen just write

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
systemUiController.isStatusBarVisible = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here How you can hide the status bar
Use this function in your Helper Object Class and call it in your activity

```
    fun hideStatusBar(window: Window, context: Context){
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window
            .decorView
            .systemUiVisibility =
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.transparent_bg_color)
    } else {
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

Call it in your Activity before set Content View.

```
hideStatusBar(window, this)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to themes.xml file. it will make the notification drawer semi-transparent.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello! Consider adding some comments or verbal explanations of what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

**100% it's will work for Hide and show statusbar & navigationbar**
**Call this methods directly for show and hide statusbar * navigationbar**

```
 private void hideSystemUI() {

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

}

private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

**For mor info [Rajmeetamil](https://www.youtube.com/c/Rajmeetamil)**

Answer (score 0):

Always put this before `setContentView` to avoid app crashing.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score -1):

Under res -> values ->styles.xml

Inside the *style* body tag paste

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
```

Comment: it is throwing error - org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 79; The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:targetApi" associated with an element type "item" is not bound.

Answer (score -1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Hello! Consider adding some comments or verbal explanations of what you're doing.