# Android hide system bar in android 3.1

Tags: android, statusbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to hide status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android)

[image]

How can I remove this statusbar in android 3.1.

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is your Problem ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Answer (score 6):

You can't.  That's not the status bar, that's the new system bar, and you can't remove it because unlike the status bar it has key navigation affordances (back and home keys).

The only things you can do with it are as described for [View.setSystemUiVisibility()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility%28int%29).  Note that on tablets you can not assume SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION will be respected; this is mainly intended for display video, so if the screen's aspect ratio allows a wide screen video to be shown without removing the navigation, then it will not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

This code will remove the notification bar and title bar programmatically (tested using Android 2.3.3).

Unfortunatly this code does not work for Android 3.0 and above.

```
//Remove notification bar 
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  

//Remove title bar 
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```