# android - How to Hide the stausbar

Tags: android, android-titlebar

I set the following property in application tag of `manifeast` file. but it hides both titlebar(Actionbar) and Statusbar.Here i want to hide only the statusbar.

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

Comment: Check out this answer,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Comment: @Austin: I need title/action bar. Your code hides both the status and title/action bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for hiding only status bar add this code in oncrete of activity:

```
// Hide the Status Bar
 
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

and remove `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` from manifest

Comment: How can i set this property in the manifeast file instead of code part?

Comment: i do't how we can do this in manifest but i'm sure this code hide only status bar

Comment: yes,this hides status bar only but my application have lot of activities thats why i am asking to set it in the manifeast.

Comment: i'm also trying find out hide only status bar from manifest if i found then i will tell u

Answer (score 1):

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

add this code to begining of your activity

Comment: This code hides the both status bar and title/action bar. But i want to hide status bar only

Comment: Just call the second function .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code snippet:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

     /* add below 2 lines*/
    getWindow().clearFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Comment: You don't want to set this to manifest. Just set inside of activity