# Hide navigation bar, but show Actionbar in Android 3.0 >

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to hide the navigation bar (where battery status, time, notifications and other stuff is shown), but I want to keep the actionbar.

How can I manage it?

```
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

This method hides everything...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself:

```
// Hide the Status Bar
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

From another question ([android - How to Hide the stausbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028820/android-how-to-hide-the-stausbar))