# Android app full screen

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen

[image: screenshot]

Got this app running in kiosk mode and would like to run it on full screen.
Already got rid of the application's grey title bar, but still got the home, volume, back and other buttons on the top bar as you can see in the picture.

The device is running android 2.2 firmware.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tablet you are running on is running a hacked version of Android, one that does not comply with the Compatibility Definition Document. As a result, you probably cannot get rid of that bar, unless you replace the firmware with something else.

The recommendations that the other provided is the right answer for compatible Android devices.

Comment: ok, thanks! but how do you know that its running a hacked version of android?

Comment: If it is running a hacked version of android, its been hacked by the manufacturers then. I installed the firmware downloaded from the manufacturer's website. The tablet is a bq verne plus btw.

Comment: @jjgl: "its been hacked by the manufacturers then" -- most likely, that is true. "how do you know that its running a hacked version of android?" -- Android 2.2 does not support that top "system bar"-style UI for HOME, MENU, and BACK.

Answer (score 13):

So there is more approaches:

First, you should specify this feature in your `Manifest.xml`

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Or in your `onCreate` method work both these approaches:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Have tried these already but only got rid of the little grey bar with the apps name on it.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Make Your activity to look something like this in manifest

```
            <activity
            android:name=".HelloActivity"
            android:label="@string/laptop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: Have already tried this too. I think this is only good for android os3?

Answer (score 1):

In android manifest use this line

```
<activity android:name=".yourActivityName"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

and in your class use this line in oncreate method

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

this code works fine for android 2.2 i have tested and its working.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity);
```