# Hide Battery,Signal and Time on an activity

Tags: android

How can I hide all things like battery,signal and time on an activity.
I am using following code for hiding title:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

But what about rest things hiding? How to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```