# How to hide status bar permanently in android?

Tags: java, android, hide, statusbar

How to hide `status bar` (phone icon,battery icon, network icon etc.) in android?

Comment: you want to do this when you are running your application? or throughtout when you are in the launcher?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Answer (score 4):

Write this code just above `setContentView(R.id.activity_main)` and it will work.

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also change theme in `Android Manifest` to hide the status bar such that you don't have to call the code in every activity.

```
<application
    ...
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
    ...
</application>
```

If you are not using Holo, you may need to change that slightly.

Alternatively, you can call this code in each activity -

**For 4.0 and Lower**

Add this in onCreate method before `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` line.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

**For 4.1 and higher**

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest you can add `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

In your Activity you can add `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

Hope this will help you in finding your solution.