# Hide status bar while having Media controller on android

Tags: android, statusbar, android-videoview, mediacontroller

i am using this method to hide status bar :

```
public static void hideStatusBar(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {
        View decorView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}
```

this works fine but when i start  video i have notice the status bar is visible again , after some test on my code i have realized that the status bar i visible after i add the MediaController .

how can i keep my full screen and still using MediaController ?

this is how i add the MediaController

```
   mMediaController = new MediaController(getContext());
   mMediaController.setAnchorView(this);
   setMediaController(mMediaController);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
...
</application>
```

or

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

and see this link:
http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

and this link:
[How to hide status bar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android)

Comment: as i wrote i can hide the status bar as you suggest but the mediaController will bring him back...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the videoView can bring back the status bar. Not sure what the behind principle is. While you can resolve it by setting a **setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener**, Something like:

```
        getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            );
        }
    });
```