# android - How to get rid of the very top bar

Tags: android

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnTna.png)

So I want to get rid of the black area at the top and the gray "news" area should be the very top of the screen. What is this section called?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251714/set-title-background-color) but it just crashed my app.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.SeanLee_TheFootballGallery_2201" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_core);

        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_01, null)));

        populateCollection();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, NewsFragment.newInstance(mCollection)).commit();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431365/how-to-hide-status-bar-in-android

Answer (score 0):

add this to your manifest  :

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: Make sure that this is implemented at the all styles files

Answer (score 0):

Please explain this a bit:-
You want to get rid of it from all the screens or in a specific screens.

Comment: all the screens!!